# Whose turn is it?

Tags: terminology

Is there a specific term for the player whose turn it is to act?

I though it was UTG but found out UTG means something entirely else.

So, is there a specific poker term for whomever is *currently* "UTG"? Other than regular terms like "current player" or "it"??

Comment: hmmm, never thought of this. What you usually hear is `Now the action is on player X`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct term is "turn to act". It is often shortened to "action".

"Player X, it's your turn to act".
"Action is on Player X".

Comment: There's also "Option". This is usually offered to the big blind when nobody raised.  I'm not sure if it's universal, but it's common in Montreal, and maybe in other French speaking casinos.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer lies in your own question.

It's the players "turn to act"

Answer (score 1):

One descriptive term is "action", used such as where is the action? The action is at X. Action is at you. Action is at the button. There is no specific descriptive term that is considered standard. Things like its here, its there, its over there, its at the button, up to, or what would you do if it were up to you, are all acceptable descriptive terms.

What I usually say to someone "Under The Gun" is, your first. As far as a term, under the gun is slang for being first to act, so the only thing that looks like it might be a term is the expression itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would just say: "It is on `name of the player`"